# DIV element not being pushed down by content inside it

Tags: php, html, css, while-loop

I have a div which is not being pushed down by the content inside it. Instead the content just overlaps the div. I assume this is because there's a PHP while loop between the div tags? How do I fix this?

```
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION["user_name"])
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}

include('header.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
if(isset($id)) {
    connect_to_db();
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM content WHERE id='$id'");
    $deleted = 'Content Successfully Deleted.<br>';
}
echo '<div id="content">';
echo '<h2>Delete Content</h2>';
if(isset($deleted)){
    echo $deleted;
}
connect_to_db();
$query="SELECT id, date, title, image FROM content ORDER BY date DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<div id="delete" align="center">';
    echo '<a href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><img src="'.$row['image'].'" style="border:1px solid black; width:100px;"><br>Delete</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the site or post the CSS? Won't be able to find the issue with the code you have posted. It seems to be that the content is in a container which is positioned absolutely, sitting on-top of the DIV you are expecting it to be in, so this has naught to do with your PHP code but rather your CSS code. Looking at your code again its probably this div: `div id="delete"` which is positioned absolutely.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysql). If you care to learn, [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a quite good PDO-related tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `overflow: hidden;` CSS rule on the div which has the overlapping content in it.

Answer (score 0):

try clearing the div inside the while loop, maybe something like

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<div id="delete" align="center">';
echo '<a href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><img src="'.$row['image'].'" style="border:1px solid black; width:100px;"><br>Delete</a>';
echo '<div style="clear:both"></div></div>';
}
```

may help?
or declare the `<a>` element as a block element?

Answer (score 0):

Using a PHP loop is not related to this issue, what matters is the HTML code that is served to your web browser.

Try adding a `clear: both;` style to the div in question:

```
<div id="delete" align="center" style="clear: both;">
```

You may also align using CSS instead of a HTML attribute:

```
<div id="delete" style="text-align: center; clear: both;">
```

**UPDATE** I see that your DIV elements are overleaping, not floating next to each other as I originally thought.

Check your CSS and see if you can find any `position: absolute` that applies to these DIV elements, and remove it. In addition, you should use `class="delete"` instead of `id="delete"`, as multiple elements should not share the same `id` attribute.

For testing, you can try:

```
<div id="delete" style="text-align: center; position: block;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried all your suggestions but nothing works! :( Yes the divs overlap. The first one (id="content") creates the main block in which all content sits, it's basically a white square. Then the other divs (id=delete) are within the content div, and are supposed to push out the size of the content div depending on how many 'delete' divs are within it. However, the content div just stays static. the Title 'Delete Content' pushes it down, but it gets stuck there. Any ideas?

Comment: Search your CSS file for `position`, what do you find? Also, please temporarily comment out all the `<style>` tags and `<link>` tags that includes css files and load your page, to confirm that this is indeed an issue related to your stylesheet. Be aware that you have a major security flaw in your code at `mysql_query("DELETE FROM content WHERE id='$id'");`, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Sorted now. thanks for the help. As for the security flaw. Have I not covered it by making sure the user needs to be logged in before any of the SQL code gets executed?

Comment: You should *always* escape user inputs in SQL, no matter how much you trust your users.